# Why I cannot access the properties of my Custom ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Ok, I created a windows control project....dropped a comboBox on it, wrote some custom code that I wanted on its event ( Text Changed event, etc) ... I can also compile it and drop it on a new WinForms App... good.

But in my sample WinForms app that I want to use it, I cannot access the properties of that combo box.. it does not list them .. properties like SelectedItems, etc...

what Am I doing wrong? this is my first time creating a custom control tho.

Thanks all

Comment: What makes you say that it is a *custom* combo?

Comment: Some code snippets would go a long way in figuring out what your trying to do. :)

Comment: just a comboBox that changes its BackColor to Yellow when nothing is picked in its list of items and the Backcolor turns back to white when an item is selected...yes! I know it is so simple that I can put the code in my project without creating a new control..but it is both for learning and also I am reusing this type of Combo in many other Forms and apps.. so its good to have it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I could fix that by Inheriting from ComboBox instead of UserConntrol which was generated by the code.
so now I am moer confused! so If I had more than one control on that border-less area then how I refer to them in my projects?

Answer (score 0):

If Intellisense is failing you, it's most likely a misplaced brace, or something similar.  Try commenting out lines with errors until your code is error-free, and try intellisensing again.

Comment: gives me this compile error: "Error 1 'RedLabel.UserControl1' does not contain a definition for 'SelectedIndex' and no extension method 'SelectedIndex' accepting a first argument of type 'RedLabel.UserControl1' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
"

Comment: I have also added the Reference of that custom control to my TestApp ... but it still gives that compile error

Comment: Does your UserControl class have a public property called 'SelectedIndex'?  Are you somehow exposing the SelectedIndex of the ComboBox?  Please show some code!